# Can't erase external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, disk-utility, secure-erase, macos-catalina

I have been trying to wipe my external hard drive (WD My Passport 2626 Media 2TB) using my MacOS Catalina 10.15.2.

I have tried each command multiple times, shut my mac off between, changed USB port...

- **Terminal**

  ```bash
  diskutil secureErase 1 *disk2*
    error:    -69759: securely erasing data to prevent recovery failed
    underlying error: 16
  ```

  ```bash
  diskutil zeroDisk force *disk2*
    error:    -69759: securely erasing data to prevent recovery failed
    underlying error: 16
  ```

  ```bash
  diskutil randomDisk 2 *disk2*
    error:    -69759: securely erasing data to prevent recovery failed
    underlying error: 16
  ```
- **Disk Utility**

  - Erase Disk > Security Option > Two-pass secure erase

    ```bash
    securely erasing data to prevent recovery failed. : (-69759) operation failed...
    ```
  - Erase Disk > Security Option > Fastest (non-secure)

    ```bash
    unable to write to the last block of the device. : (-69760) operation failed
    ```

About the hard drive:

**WD My Passport 2626 Media 2TB**

```
Volume type:       Uninitialized
Writable:          No
Is case-sensitive: No
Volume capacity:   2 000 356 289 472 

Available space (Purgeable + Free): 0

Purgeable space:   0
Free Space:        0
Used Space.:       2 000 356 289 472  
Owners enabled:    No
Is encrypted:      No
Can be verified:   No
```

Comment: I don't know squat about Mac, but if you don't get an answer you could always try using a GParted Live CD or USB - https://gparted.org/livecd.php

Comment: How long does it take before `diskutil` commands return with the error message? If it takes some time may be the HDD has defect sectors that can't be overwritten and therefore wiping fails...

Answer (score 1):

Check you SMART parameters running smartmontools.
https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download
Redirect the output of the smartctl command to a file with a command like
smartctl -a /dev/sdb > smart.txt before trying to delete your hard drive in a different way and post smart.txt here.